# crontab run sequentially

Tags: 12.04, bash, cron

I have to run `crontab` in `xvfb display mode` forever when the system restarts...below is crontab code....

```
@reboot nohup Xvfb :1 -screen 0 1024x768x24 & export DISPLAY=":1"
@reboot /usr/bin/forever start -c /usr/bin/node test/app.js
```

After the system reboots... I have to run both the commands sequentially..second command works fine...but i think Xvfb is not starting...if possible i want to run xvfb also in forever mode if it stops unexpectedly,how to fix this?

i have also tried running script...

```
#!/bin/sh
/usr/bin/nohup Xvfb :1 -screen 0 1024x768x24 & 
export DISPLAY=":1";
/usr/bin/forever start -c /usr/bin/node test/app.js; 


@reboot start_me.sh
```